# Keeping monitor Dell desk monitor 'connected' to dell studio 15 laptop?

Tags: external-monitor

First of all, I am new to Ubuntu 10.04 but it is love at first sight and the only windows I will see again are in my house and car!

Each time I disconnect my Dell Studio 15 from my Dell 36" monitor, I have to reconnect through the System/Monitor protocol.

Question: Is there a way to set it up so once I slide my laptop under the stand, reconnect monitor cable, 3 usb's and press start that the Monitor screen will go 'live' without having to start all over?

Comment: Do you mind providing information about your graphics card? In my experience with nVidias, they don't have that issue and you can do what you wish if the drivers are properly installed. Let's see what is your graphics card in order to gather some information about it.

Comment: 256MB ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3450

Comment: I took it off the spec sheet from when i got the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the proprietary fglrx-driver supplied by AMD. Last time I checked it doesn't yet support Xrandr 1.2, which is the part of the display server that does the magic you're after (activate monitor automatically when connected).

You might want to try the open source radeon driver available, which is called xserver-xorg-video-radeon (find it through Synaptic). As stated here: http://wiki.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature the R600-series (your HD 3450) should be working with xrandr1.2.

This will be a trade-off between performance and better multimonitor support. The situation is exactly the same for me with nvidia.